# angular with wavesurfer.js Doesn't work in IE10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, plugins

I am building an angular application in which I use wavesurfer.js plugin to visualize media into wave format. It works fine in chrome but it doesn't in IE10 and IE11 even. Please help me out.

I get mp3 file to play in a object Tag.

```
<object id="global" name="" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="ZeroClipboard.swf?noCache=1425648511012"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"><param name="allowNetworking" value="all"><param name="menu" value="false"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="flashvars" value="trustedOrigins=127.0.0.1%3A1337%2C%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A1337%2Chttp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A1337&amp;swfObjectId=global-zeroclipboard-flash-bridge&amp;jsVersion=2.2.0"><div id="global-zeroclipboard-flash-bridge_fallbackContent">&nbsp;</div></object>
```

Error I get in IE10 is "TypeError: Object doesn't support this action"
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support [Web Audio API](http://caniuse.com/#search=web-audio), which wavesurfer relies on.

From (wavesurfer homepage](http://www.wavesurfer.fm/):

> wavesurfer.js runs on modern browsers supporting Web Audio. Including Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Mobile Safari and Opera.

Modernizr's wiki lists HTML5 polyfill options, but I can't say it will work with wavesurfer library. [Link to HTML5 audio polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#audio)